# Is Lucida Sans Typewriter installed on Mac OS X by default?

Tags: fonts

I'm updating my font stacks and I'm finding contradictory information on the install base for Lucida Sans Typewriter.

According to [this page](http://www.codestyle.org/servlets/FontStack?stack=&generic=monospace) and [this page](http://cssfontstack.com/), it is installed on 99% of all Macs.

However, according to the [List of Typefaces Included with Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Mac_OS_X) (see Reference Links at the bottom of the page), it isn't installed by default.

Lucida Sans Typewriter is included with every MS Office release since NT (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=630) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837463)), but I can't imagine 99% of all Mac users have it installed.

Can any OS X users help clarify?

**UPDATE:**

For those who *really* want to know, according to my research the font `OCR A Extended` is also installed by MSOffice along with `Lucida Sans Typewriter`. According to the [statistics on codestyle.org](http://www.codestyle.org/servlets/FontStack?stack=&generic=monospace), OCR A Extended has a 67% install base on Win machines only. Thus, a conclusion you could draw is that Lucida Sans Typewriter also has a 67% install base on Win machines only. However this information is probably still inaccurate because Mac users also use MSOffice, thus they *should* have at least a small percentage install base.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple's own per-version font lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Mac_OS_X#References) say no, repeatedly. (Linking to the Wikipedia refs since there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get them all at once at Apple's site.)
I just checked on a fairly stock OS X 10.7 install: it's not there.

You're right to think it's suspicious so many Mac users would have Office installed; This leads into why you shouldn't trust the information at those two sites: they're not backed up. For what it's worth, the OSX/Office market share [*has* been pretty high](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13505_3-10134174-16.html)[2009], but something like 99% really does need a citation. That said, when you account for the *source* of information(see next paragraph), it's possible to see how that number could become inflated.

Code Style's data looks useless. First, it's based on a [survey](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/index.shtml), so the results are skewed toward a self-selected group of people who even know/care what fonts are and are generally going to be developers of some sort. These systems are *always* abnormal versus you likely building your sites for a general audience. Most importantly: 99% *of what*? There's not a single mention of how many people actually took their survey.

CSS Font Stack's percentages are, for any formal purposes, completely made up. Here's the [entirety of the developer's explanation of the project](http://snapsize.com/css-font-stack).